# Are there any side effects of returning from inside a using() statement?

Tags: c#, using

Returning a method value from **inside** a using statement that gets a DataContext seems to always work **fine**, like this:

```
public static Transaction GetMostRecentTransaction(int singleId)
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var transaction = (from t in db.Transactions
                              orderby t.WhenCreated descending
                              where t.Id == singleId
                              select t).SingleOrDefault();
        return transaction;
    }
}
```

But I always feel like I should be **closing something** before I break out of the using brackets, e.g. by defining transaction **before** the using statement, get it's value **inside** the brackets, and then returning **after** the brackets.

**Would defining and returning the variable outside the using brackets be better practice or conserve resources in any way?**

Comment: It might be interesting to look at the general IL for variants of this.  I suspect that there would be little difference in the generated IL.  I normally wouldnt even bother declaring the var transaction - just return the result of the expression.

Answer (score 166):

No, I think it's clearer this way. Don't worry, `Dispose` will still be called "on the way out" - and only *after* the return value is fully evaluated. If an exception is thrown at any point (including evaluating the return value) `Dispose` will still be called too.

While you certainly *could* take the longer route, it's two extra lines that just add cruft and extra context to keep track of (mentally). In fact, you don't really need the extra local variable - although it can be handy in terms of debugging. You *could* just have:

```
public static Transaction GetMostRecentTransaction(int singleId)
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        return (from t in db.Transactions
                orderby t.WhenCreated descending
                where t.Id == singleId
                select t).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Indeed, I might even be tempted to use dot notation, and put the `Where` condition within the `SingleOrDefault`:

```
public static Transaction GetMostRecentTransaction(int singleId)
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        return db.Transactions.OrderByDescending(t => t.WhenCreated)
                              .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == singleId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sine it's you @jon, is it still safe if an exception gets thrown inside the using block?

Comment: yes. using is simply syntactic sugar for a try/finally construct

Comment: @David: As Mitch says, it's fine - I've updated the answer to make that clearer :)

Comment: Why use OrderByDescending in combination with SingleOrDefault?

Comment: @erikkallen: LINQ doesn't have a "MaxBy", unfortunately - so you can't get the row with the maximal value. For LINQ to Objects you can write your own fairly easily, but I'm not sure of a better way of doing it in this case. What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet wouldn't it be better (performance wise) to return the value after finalize in cases where the returning value can be materialized so that all using statements don't keep resources for the life time of the materialized result? (e.g. returning decompressed Zlib file contents after using different streams to read and decompress a Zlib file)

Comment: @Menol: How would the `using` statements do that? I don't understand your point, I'm afraid. (And nothing's being finalized here... it's being disposed. That's not the same thing.)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I meant calling the finally block. Im currently writing a method that reads a zlib file, decompresses it and returns plain text. The example on MSDN uses several nested using statements and the plain text can be materialized in the innermost using block. Wouldn't it be better if I return the plain text after coming out of usings than return it from inside using statements? wouldn't returning from inside usings cause delay in disposing resources I dont need anymore?

Comment: @Menol: Why would it delay anything? It sounds like you should probably ask a new question with details.

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually thoroughly reading your answer, MSDN article on using and a quick LinqPad play around helped me to understand what I was confused about. The using will call dispose when the method returns unless the resource it's linked to is still open. I need to read more on how memory allocation works when a method returns a variable. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 33):

Have a look at this

[Understanding the 'using' statement in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tinguusingstatement.aspx)

> The CLR converts your code into MSIL.
>   And the using statement gets
>   translated into a try and finally
>   block. This is how the using statement
>   is represented in IL. A using
>   statement is translated into three
>   parts: acquisition, usage, and
>   disposal. The resource is first
>   acquired, then the usage is enclosed
>   in a try statement with a finally
>   clause. The object then gets disposed
>   in the finally clause.

Comment: That translates the question to: Any side effects of returning from the try-block of a try-finally?

Comment: No, the finally will always be called. http://www.techinterviews.com/interview-questions-for-c-developers

Answer (score 6):

There are **no** side effects of returning from inside a `using()` statement.

Whether it makes the most readable code is another discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's all the same. There's nothing bad in the code. The .NET framework wouldn't care where the object is created. The thing that matters is whether it is referenced or not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there can be a side effect. For example, if you use the same technique in ASP.NET MVC Action method, you will get the following error: "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection"

```
public ActionResult GetMostRecentTransaction(int singleId)
{
    using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var transaction = (from t in db.Transactions
                              orderby t.WhenCreated descending
                              where t.Id == singleId
                              select t).SingleOrDefault();
        return PartialView("_transactionPartial", transaction);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you define transaction outside of using statement, you will got the same error.  using keyword is unrelated in this case.