# Are there any side effects of returning from inside a foreach statement?

Tags: c#, foreach

Similar to my question about [returning from inside a **using statement**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369887/are-there-any-side-effects-of-returning-from-inside-a-using-statement) (whose answer was generally "**yes, it's ok**") I'm wondering if returning from **inside a foreach** statement is similarly devoid of **side-effects** and considered **accepted practice**, or when I do this am I leaving a **pointer** hanging in the middle an **enumeration** somewhere internally, etc.

Here's an example:

```
public string GetCurrentTransaction(string idText)
{
    foreach (var transaction in transactions)
    {
        if (idText.IsEquivalentTo(transaction.IdText))
        {
            return transaction.Content;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nope, dont see any issue with that.

From [foreach, in (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(VS.80).aspx)

> A foreach loop can also be exited by
>   the goto, return, or throwstatements.

Answer (score 5):

As long as nothing there implements IDisposable (or you have a `using` block around it), then that should be fine.

As far as I know, it's a fairly common and accepted practice and, as Astander mentions in his post, the documentation for `foreach` condones it as a legitimate practice.

Comment: Actually, `foreach` will dispose the `IEnumerator<>`, so that you're fine if the enumerator itself is disposable. See also the accepted answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232558/why-ienumerator-of-t-inherts-from-idisposable-but-non-generic-ienumerator-does-n

Answer (score 2):

other than it being a small code smell to return from multiple points in methods (adds to the methods cyclomatic complexity) there is no technical reason to worry about.

Comment: +1 I agree, it will add some complexity.  I would create a string variable and assign it when the text is found and break from the loop.  But from a technical standpoint, nothing to worry about (except for IDisposable as others have mentioned).  Its probably more a coding style question.

Comment: for simple "find the element and return it or return null if not found" i think it's ok to have 2 exit points as those functions are short enough so you can spot both return points easily and you don't have to carry another "returnValue" variable around.

Comment: IMHO, there is no code smell here. It's more readable then writing return values to variables and continuing to the end when you want to make sure the nothing more is done. And it's more readable then having tons of nested if statements (if (stillNotFound) stuff).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I'll make an educated guess: Since an enumerator typically doesn't implement IDisposable, it *should* be simply garbage-collected, because otherwise *each* use of that enumerator would leak unmanaged resources. Of course, technically, you can implement an enumerator that has side-effects on its own...

In other words, I never felt bad about returning from within a `foreach` block. I'd expect the language to handle things, just like with a `using` statement, where the language ensures that the object is disposed of (by implicitly calling Dispose in a `finally` block).

Comment: Enumerators (inheriting from `IEnumerable<>`) do implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: `IEnumerator<T>` is derived from `IDisposable`, true (didn't know that), but `IEnumerator` is not. However, `foreach` starting with C# 2.0 calls Dispose in the `finally` block, so the language handles it, as I'd expect. You can safely return from a `foreach`block.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember the enumeration stays on this position until the next foreach loop. This is however no problem as any following foreach returns the position back to the start of the enumeration. In short: It has no bad side effects unless you rely on IEnumerator.Current to have a specific value (which would be bad anyways).